# safari target="_blank" and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, safari

I have the following html code:

```
<a href="url.com" target="_blank" onclick="jsFunction1('var');jsFunction2();">image</a>
```

I have the following js functions:

```
var jsFunction = function(button) {
    var site = encodeURIComponent("site name");
    var lid = "lid";
    var src = "src";
    var pf = "platfrom";
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.myurl.com/page.php?site="+site+"&lid="+lid+"&src="+src+"&pf="+pf+"&bt="+button,
        async: false
    });
}

var jsFunction2 = function() {
    var lid = "lid";
    var offer = "offer";
    var platform = "platfrom";
    var site = encodeURIComponent("site name");
    var aid = "aid";
    var sid = encodeURIComponent("sid");
    var placement = "placement";
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.myurl.com/pagetwo.php?lid="+lid+"&offer="+offer+"&platform="+platform+"&site="+site+"&aid="+aid+"&sid="+sid+"&placement="+placement,
        async: false
    });   

    window.location = "mypage.php";
}
```

This seems to function normally in all browsers except Safari 5.1.9 and above.  Upon clicking the link it opens a new window/tab and the parent window is directed forward as it should.  However, in safari an new window is not opened but the parent window still moves forward.  Any ideas as to why safari has this behavior and how to work around or fix it?

Comment: instead of target="_blank" you could try window.open in your js (but you may be blocked by popup blockers)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid and it's beyond me at this point as to why this does not work in safari

Comment: maybe you should write `onclick="... return jsfunction2();"` and have jsfunction2 return true or false.

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work either.